# i have a login page in codeigniter but it does not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I am working on a login system with Codeigniter. I got no errors but it does not work.

This is my form:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 bg-primary">
    <?php echo validation_errors() ?>
    <?php echo form_open('admin') ?>
    <h3 class="text-center"><?php echo $title ?></h3><hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>UserName:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder=" password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Log in">
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close() ?>
</div>
```

controller:

```
class admin extends CI_Controller{
//login
public function index(){
    $data['title'] = 'Login';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === false ){
        $this->load->view('admin/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('admin/login_form',$data);
        $this->load->view('admin/footer');
    }
    else{
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
        $user_id = $this->admin_model->login($password,$username);
        if($user_id){
            $userdata = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $userdata);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('logged_in','you are now logged in');
            die('success');
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'login credential are wrong');
            die('fail');
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

and this is the model:

```
<?php 
class admin_model extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->database('theory');
    }
    //login 
    public function login($username,$password){
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $result = $this->db->get('users');
        if($result->num_rows() == 1){
            return $result->row(0)->id;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

it give no error but also doesn't work i can't understand why.
please help guys

Comment: controller code paste??

Comment: Please check and give us correct code.

Comment: you controller name give "Admin"

Comment: sorry guys it's updated now

Comment: class admin extends CI_Controller{  change to class Admin extends CI_Controller{

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: just for the knowledge, CodeIgniter has an error log system so you can simply see what's happening or if you would like to go advance then use the debugger.  this is for a better understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

`$user_id = $this->admin_model->login($password,$username);`

Should be

`$user_id = $this->admin_model->login($username,$password);`